# SharePoint 2010 to Sitecore 9 update 1

Tags: migration

I have to migrate data from SharePoint 2010 to Sitecore 9 Update 1 instance. There is one connector "[SharePoint Connect 2.2](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/SharePoint_Connect/2_0/SharePoint_Connect_23.aspx)" for this. Drawback is that "SharePoint Connect is not supported on Sitecore 9 (and greater)" based on note from Sitecore about this module.

Is there any other way to migrate data from SharePoint 2010 to Sitecore 9 Update 1 including SharePoint media?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have various options:

1. Create instance of Sitecore 8 with Sharepoint Connect connector installed. Do the migration there and then create package with migrated items and deploy/install them via Installation Wizard to your Sitecore 9
2. Clone repository with source code for Sharepoint Connect connector from here -> https://github.com/Sitecore/SharePoint-Connect . Adjust code to fit your purposes and tweak it to work with Sitecore 9. Release it maybe then in your own repository as fork. Maybe also somebody else could you it in the future.
3. Use [Data Exchange Framework](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Data_Exchange_Framework/2x/Data_Exchange_Framework_201.aspx) and create similar Sharepoint provider as exists for [Dynamics 365](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Dynamics_CRM_Connect/2x/Sitecore_Connect_for_Microsoft_Dynamics_365_for_Sales_201.aspx) or [Salesforce](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Salesforce_Connect/2x/Sitecore_Connect_for_Salesforce_CRM_201.aspx). You don't need to create complete implementation based on these two. Do only Minimum Viable Product that suit your requirements.
4. Create your custom migration script as a console app, ps1 script or anything else. This will read data from Sharepoint and based on requirements create corresponding items in Sitecore in some hierarchies. Create appropriate templates, fields for future Sitecore items. Don't forget to use buckets if items exceed 100+ child elements. This will help you repeat migration between different environments also to catch all exceptions / edge cases during testing of migration.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Quick questions - Can packages of Sitecore 8 dircetly be installed on Sitecore 9? How to migrate SharePoint media files and change their links inside content in sitecore

Comment: If we are talking about packages with content items that you have migrated, than I think there should not be any problem. For the second question, I cannot answer this as I haven't worked with that Sharepoint connector before. I don't know how content is created on Sitecore side.

Comment: I would recommend doing small Proof of concept and migrate only one page or at least one piece of content with that connector to Sitecore 8. You will see how it works and based on outcome you will either continue or do another POC for another option from my list.

Comment: Thanks for your pointers @peter-prochazka . I will work on that and update about my outcome.

Comment: @SurendrASharmA .. I have done some upgrades and usually taking a package from an older version of Sitecore and installing into a new one is not a problem unless there are major changes. Looks like the package solution will work. As always try it out first. See this post - https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/t/8659

Comment: @PeterProchazka I done this "SharePoint to Sitecore" migration and publishing an ebook at http://www.sitecorelessons.com/2018/10/ebook-sharepoint-to-sitecore-strategy.html

Comment: Looks very good @SurendrASharmA. Good job!